# Does this imply that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are isomorphic as fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Suppose $F_1$ and $F_2$ be two finite fields such that additive groups of $F_1$ and $F_2$ are isomorphic and also  multiplicative groups of $F_1$ and $F_2$ are isomorphic.Does this imply that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are isomorphic as fields ?(Without using uniqueness of finite fields)

Any hints/ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the fact that the additive groups are isomorphic immediately implies that the multiplicative groups are isomorphic, since the multiplicative groups are cyclic, and so if the additive groups are isomorphic, then the fields must have the same number of elements, and thus the multiplicative groups have the same number of elements two.

Of course the uniqueness of finite groups solves the problem as soon as it is posed, so I guess you are wondering if it is possible to prove elementarily that any additive homo/iso-morphism between fields is automatically a multiplicative homo/iso-morphism too. That is not the case since the additive isomorphism $x\mapsto -x$ is not a multiplicative isomorphism.

Comment: I am not sure that I have understood your answer.Actually I am trying to use above problem in proving uniqueness of finite fields.   Can you explain "How can I get field isomorphism from given two group isomorphism" ?

Comment: The uniqueness of finite fields says any two finite fields of the same size are isomorphic, so an isomorphism exists. The proof is classical but it does not proceed by concocting an isomorphism from an additive iso and a multiplicative iso. Is there any reason you don't just study the standard proof of the uniqueness of finite fields?

Comment: Dear,I know the standard proof of this result.But here I am trying to prove this result using the fact that any finite field is a vector space over $Z/pZ$ (Hence isomorphic additive groups) and as multiplicative group is a cyclic group(Hence isomorpphic multiplicative groups).So I don't want to use "uniqueness of Finite fields".